# How to print process name in StartUp.cs for .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

From yesterday I have started learning **.netcore**. I have installed .netcore 2.2 & .netcore 3.1 in my machine.

In **.netcore 2.2**, I am able to print the process name on the website.
i.e. 
I had written this below code in Startup.cs in an empty .netcore web application:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response
    .WriteAsync(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
});
```

But now in **.netcore 3.1**, by default, it is calling the razor pages. So, I tried to replace that code with the above code, but I am getting this below error:

> 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'WriteAsync' and no
>   accessible extension method 'WriteAsync' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?

It seems the extension method '**WriteAsync**' has been removed in **.netcore 3.1**.

So, how do I display that now?

Comment: That's odd. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponseWritingExtensions_WriteAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponse_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) says that `WriteAsync` still applies to 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this using

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```